# If gamma radiation is harmful to humans, why isn't natural light fatal?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, radiation, biology, gamma-rays

If gamma radiation (which is comprised of photons) is harmful to humans when in close proximity, then why do photons in natural light from the sun not mutate human DNA to the same extent? I know that skin cancer can be caused by radiation, but it is normally UV that causes mutations, not the gamma to my knowledge.

Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick note:  At an atomic level, damage is caused by breaking chemical bonds or by liberating electrons.  Both types of interactions have minimum energy thresholds, below which the incident particle [whether photon or massive particle] should not be able to affect the molecule/atom.  Visible light does not have enough energy to break(liberate) any chemical bonds(electrons) [of which I am aware] but gamma rays are high enough energy to break(liberate) most, if not all, depending on circumstances.

Comment: So have much energy do gamma photons have? Since both are photons and hence have the same weight, and also both travel at the speed of light, the energy is surely equal; or is it not? That is it we use E = mc²

Comment: No, photons are massless particles.  They carry momentum, from which one derives energy.  The energy of a photon is given by $E = h \ \nu = \tfrac{h \ c}{\lambda}$, where $h$ is Planck's constant, $\nu$ is the frequency, $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum, and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.  Thus, higher(shorter) frequency(wavelength) photons have more energy.

Comment: So E = mc² is incorrect or does the equation you mentioned exclusively regard kinetic energy?

Comment: The energy-momentum relation is given by:$$E^{2} = \left( p \ c \right)^{2} + \left( m \ c^{2} \right)^{2}$$ where $p$ is the momentum and $m$ is the rest mass.  Thus, the $E = m \ c^{2}$ relationship only applies to a massive particle in its rest frame.  For a photon, the 2nd term goes to zero and the momentum is given in terms of the frequency or wavelength, as I stated above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the frequency spectrum of electromagnetic radiation is important in showing the energy carried by the individual photons. Note in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) gamma rays are the highest energy rays, the photons have energy of MeV, nuclear reaction energies. Visible and ultraviolet light have energies of electron volt, a thousand times lower.

Visible light can transfere energy to the electrons around the atom, but gamma rays can destroy the nuclei of an atom, dispersing the thousand times more energy in the cells.

Note that the wavelength of gamma rays is very small, which makes it penetrating , much more than visible light which has a much higher wavelength, appropriate to molecular distances.

Comment: Gamma radiation doesn't destroy nuclei of cells ... or at least, not any more than they destroy the rest of the cells (this happens with high enough intensity). They cause mutations in the DNA molecules of the cells, which reside in the nuclei. This eventually leads to cancer.

Comment: But aren't gamma rays essentially just visible light if they are photons? Is the only difference wavelength?

Comment: @Charlie -- By way of analogy, a semi truck and a moped are both vehicles. One will cause rather extensive damage and the other little or no damage should they rear-end you at 16 kph (10 mph).

Comment: Cheers for the analogy

Comment: @Charlie "But aren't gamma rays essentially just visible light if they are photons? Is the only difference wavelength?' They are light, but they are not visible light. You're right that the only difference is wavelength, we can only see very narrow band of wavelengths. Almost all photons are invisible to our eyes. Radio waves and x-rays are also just photons. But that difference in wavelength also is a difference in energy level which due to quantum effects also causes differences in whether a material is transparent to that wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

In a crux, Gamma rays can cause DNA mutations too but under heavy exposure to them, this would be the least of your concern, as your cells would just instantly die.

In more details, for visible light, as well as UV, the energy of the photons is enough to make electrons in atoms and molecules jump to higher energy levels, which can be enough to break some chemical bonds and create chemicals harmful to the body. So, to address your specific point, most skin cancers develop because UVA photons interaction with the molecule of skin cells result in the creations of so-called free radicals and oxydising compounds, which may then damage the DNA in the nucleus of the cell. This requires long and repeated exposures.

On the other hand, gamma rays pack about one million times more energy. So they can do much more damage, including:

- completely ejecting an electron from its atom/molecule, that electron can then in turn do more damage;
- for very energetic gamma rays, through interaction with a nucleus, the gamma photon can disappear into an electron and a positron (same particle as the electron but with a negative charge), and again these flying particles can do more damage.

Some of this damage is of the same kind as for UVA but some of it is way more serious: direct destruction of biological tissues, DNA included but not only. Hence my introductory remark: if heavily exposed to gamma rays, DNA mutation and skin cancer is the least of your concerns!

Answer (score 0):

Gamma rays are harmful for your body because of their high energy. We know that the energy of a wave is directly proportional to its frequency, 
                        E=hv 
where 'v' is the frequency and 'h' the Planks const.
Now gamma rays have the highest frequency and so high energy. But visible light on the other hand has relatively lesser energy and hence not harmful for your body.